# JQuery - best way to swap in and out parts of the UI

Tags: javascript, jquery

What's the best way to "preserve" and "re-display" portions of an html page, along with jquery event handlers you've set up?

More detail:

I'm writing a "one-page javascript application" that lets users perform two different calculations. The user selects which calculation they want by clicking a radio button.

When they click radio button A, a big part of the UI needs to get displayed with appropriate html controls (and jquery event handlers) that allow the user to enter the parameters for calculation A.

Likewise, if the user clicks radio button B, that section of the page needs instead to show all the controls (and its associated jquery event handlers) that allow the user to enter the parameters for calculation B.

My question is how to best handle the swapping of calculation A and B's html controls and their associated jquery event handlers?

I had thought about just using jquery's .html() to get and set the parameter section part of the page, but I'm thinking that will not preserve any event handlers that I'd set up for those controls. Is that right?  In that case, I'd need to either re-wire up the event handlers as the user switches between calculations or do something else.

(In essence I think what I want to do is to be able to preserve a chunk of the dom (which hopefully includes jquery event handlers) but I don't write a ton of jquery and am I'm not sure how to approach that... I'm wondering if I could get the whole parameter section of a page represented as a jquery node, and save that off (to a js variable) and restore it, as needed, if that would do the trick??

Thanks for any ideas!
Michael

Comment: Use `.clone`? But are you sure you need to retain the exact copy or can you reload it?

Comment: well, as it stands, I was not planning on reloading (ie via ajax) the "parameter section" of the page from the server each time the user toggles between calculation types. Instead, I was hoping to supply my JS page with everything it needs up front (ie when the user first browses to that page) and the two "chunks of html" representing each calculation, would be held in java script variables - to be "plugged into" the page as the user chooses one calc or the other.. and hoping to retain any user enter values, and jquery event handlers I'd set up..

Comment: I'd just hide/show, then, as Matt suggests, unless there's a compelling reason not to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Honestly, usually it's easier just to `hide()`/ `show()` elements rather than removing them/ re-adding them.

Add a `calculation-1` class to elements you want to be visible for the first calculation, and `calculation-2` for the second calculation elements. This will let you get a jQuery variable of all calculation 1 and 2 elements via `$('.calculation-1')` and `$('.calculation-2`).

You can then add an event handler for the radio's that `hide()` and `show()` the elements accordingly.

---

If you use `html()`, you'll lose events bound to the elements children. **Unless** you attach your handlers to an ancestor which you *don't* remove.

You can also use [`detach()`](http://api.jquery.com/detach), which will remove the elements from the DOM, but persist the event handlers you added. However, if your elements are dotted all over the DOM, it's hard to track their origional position, and TBH is more effort than it's worth.

Comment: Detach could be good. In my case, my parameter controls are not scattered all over the DOM.. I have one dedicated DIV that will act as a parent to all of the parameters. When radio A is selected, that div's content will be populated with a "tree" of controls representing calc A. If radio B is selected, then that DIV will be repopulated with a tree of  controls for calc B.

Comment: @MichaelRayLovett: In which case yes, `detach()` could work; you'll still have to save the elements in a variable though to restore them later (like you alluded to in your question). I'd still consider `hide()`/ `show()` though ;).

Comment: So in your idea of hide()/show(), the page would initially be populated with both sets of parameter sections (each enclosed in a div, for example) that are both children of some parent div.. and only one is hidden/shown at a time?

Comment: @MichaelRayLovett: Exactly.